# How to inactivate buttons that have not been pressed

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, performance

I'm a very unexperienced programmer, so please bear with me for my lack of knowledge.

I have a program with 168 different buttons, which each count how many times they have been each pressed. After having either pressed or not pressed all of the buttons i need to inactivate and grey-out those which have not been pressed. So far I've used an 3D array to store how many times each button has been pressed, and have made a simple code:

```
if(a[0][0][0]<1)
{
    ImageButton button_a1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button1a);
    button_ca1.setEnabled(false);
    button_ca1.setAlpha(6);
}
```

The only problem is that since each `buttonID` is different i have to do this 168 separated times. Is there any way to make this into a simple loop that doesn't take up over 1000 lines of code?

The program is written using `Eclipse` and is used for an `Android` app.

Comment: Why a 3d array? seems a 1d array of ints will do?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I need to store multiple values for some stuffe arranged on a shelf. Hence the 2d to most simply illustrate the shelf and the 3'rd dimension to store the different values for each position on the shelf :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the buttons are in same layout, you can use `getChildCount()`:

```
LinearLayout layout = setupLayout();
int count = layout.getChildCount();
View v = null;
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
    v = layout.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof ImageButton) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
        v.setAlpha(6); 
    }
}
```

If not, simply create a `Set`, `List` or `Array` with all buttons and iterate over it:

```
List<ImageButton> buttons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();

// be sure buttons is visible in the method
// when creating the buttons put them inside the list
```

Then  in your method:

```
if(a[0][0][0]<1)
{
    // disable all buttons
    for(ImageButton button : buttons) {
        button.setEnabled(false);
        button.setAlpha(6);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely there is an easier way?  The buttons have a parent or owner that has a container of child components that can be iterated, no?

Comment: check my edit @MartinJames I was still writting answer

Comment: Also, have the button components not got an auxiliary object member that could be used to store the count?